# How to move an object back and forth between QThreads in Pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

In my program (using Python 2.7), I create an object containing some important data and methods. Some of the methods are CPU hungry, so in certain cases I move the object to a new QThread for the duration of the CPU intensive methods, then have them come back to the main thread. At a later point, when a CPU intensive method is called, I would like to move the object to another QThread again, however this fails saying "Current thread is not the object's thread".

Here is a trivial example which reproduces the problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from time import sleep

class ClassA(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lineEdit=QtGui.QLineEdit()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.show()
        self.obj=ClassC(self)        
        self.executeProgram()
    def executeProgram(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText("Starting new thread...")
        self.thread=QtCore.QThread()
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)        
        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.doWork)
        self.obj.doingWork.connect(self.updateGui)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.killThread)
        self.thread.start()
    def updateGui(self,message):
        self.lineEdit.setText(message)
    def killThread(self):
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()
        self.obj.finished.disconnect()
        self.executeProgram()

class ClassC(QtCore.QObject):
    finished=QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    doingWork=QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
            super(ClassC, self).__init__()
    def doWork(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.doingWork.emit("doing work: iteration "+str(i))
            sleep(1)
        self.finished.emit()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    obj=ClassA()
    app.exec_()
```

Is it possible to move an object to a different QThread multiple times? If so, how would I fix my code to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note `moveToThread` must be called on the thread that the object currently belongs to, so you may need to move the object back to the main thread before moving it to yet another thread.

Add the line `mainThread = QtCore.QThread.currentThread()` somewhere at the top, and put `self.moveToThread(mainThread)` right before emitting the `finished` signal.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for your reply. Class B **is** indeed running in a different thread. Overriding the `run` method of `QThread` is not necessary and is [no longer recommended by QT](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#note-5).

Comment: No, it doesn't. (If you're not convinced, trying printing the value of ```QThread.currentThreadId()``` in a few places.) The ```QThread``` you've created lives in the main thread, so when it dispatches the ```started``` signal it is dispatched on the main thread. You need to use a different signal or the ```invokeMethod``` method suggested by that link.

Comment: I edited the code to show that it's working (sorry I had to make the connection after moveToThread()

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had assumed the thread would automatically be moved back to the parent thread after quitting the worker thread, but that's clearly not the case.

Adding `self.moveToThread(QtGui.QApplication.instance().thread())` just before the finished signal is emitted also works!

Comment: For C++/Qt Users: `this->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());`

Comment: For me using `QtGui.QApplication.instance().thread()` did not work, but storing the `QThread.currentThread()` earlier worked perfectly.  Thanks @BenjaminPeterson!